# Using a variable in the 'to' of the 'for' loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop

The general syntax for a `for` loop in Matlab is :

```
  for j = 1 to 5
    %body
  end
```

I want to have a variable whose value is calculated at run time depending on the user input to be used for controlling the number of times the `for` loop is to be run.

So I want to have:

```
m = input('Some Message');
n = ....% Some Calculations using user input 'm'
for j = 1 to n
  %body
end
```

I tried this, but am getting an error -

```
Undefined function 'to' for input arguments of type 'char'.
```

Matlab is considering the variable `n` as a character instead of a variable.

P.S: I am new to Matlab, I searched a lot online, but couldn't get a solution for this. Please help.

Comment: `to` is not part of Matlab's `for`-loop syntax. You should try `for j = 1:n`. Matlab's for basically iterates over the elements of a vector so for example you could be do for `j = [1 7 3 9 2 0]` or `v=[1 7 3 9 2 0]; for j=v` to iterate over an arbitrary set. The syntax `1:n` is just short hand for creating the vector `[1,2,...,n-1,n]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, have you tried this syntax:

```
for j=1:n
  %body
end
```

I don't see the word "to" in the [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/loop-control-statements.html).  So the for loop syntax you have above would not be valid Matlab syntax.  The other thing to consider is that n is being interpreted as a character and not a number.

Comment: `n` is being considered as a character only because `to` is being considered as a function. With the correct syntax, `n` will no longer be considered as a character.

Answer (score 4):

The error message seems quite readable. This it not valid Matlab syntax. You would write a for loop of n repititons like this

```
m = input('Some Message: ');
if strcmp(m, 'foo')
    n = 7;
else
    n = 5;
end

for j = 1:n
    fprintf('%d\n', j);
end
```

Comment: Oh right, thanks. I was looking at the MuPad Documentation for the for loop syntax.

Comment: This is correct but doesn't address the OP's question about using a variable. If you added a sentance about using variables with this syntax, this would be the most correct answer so far.